# Converting PHP BBCode REGEX to JavaScript, can someone help pinpoint an issue?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am trying to convert the following PHP REGEX into JavaScript:

```
$article_f = preg_replace('#\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]#iUs', '<b>$1</b>', $article_text);
```

I have come up with the following JavaScript:

```
 article_f = article_f .replace(/\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]/gi, '<b>$1</b>');
```

For some reason this is allowing a match to go ignored if it is on the same line as another match, it will actually combine them into one large match, e.g.:

```
[b] this is bold[/b] and [b] this is too [/b]
```

Will be replaced with

```
<b> this is bold[/b] and [b] this is too </b>
```

Any ideas one how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this pattern instead:

```
/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/gi
```

the problem was that + quantifier was greedy (default behaviour) and thus `.+` captures all that he can (ie : `this is bold[/b] and [b] this is too`). If you add a question mark the quantifier becomes ungreedy (=lazy) and stop at the first closing bbcode tag.

In the php pattern you can see the U modifier at the end which switch all greedy quantifiers to lazy and all lazy quantifiers to greedy. It's the reason why `.+` in the php pattern is lazy.(The default behaviour is inverted).

You can notice too the s modifier in the php pattern. s stands for *single line*. That means that the dot can match newlines too. But Javascript doesn't have an equivalent. 
To have the same with Javascript you must replace the dot by `[\s\S]`, otherwhise `.+`  will stop the match at the first newline.

The "perfect" translation of the php pattern is:

```
/\[b\]([\s\S]+?)\[\/b\]/gi
```